# Calculating Vin/Vout of this circuit

Tags: amplifier, voltage-divider, calculation

I am trying to calculate the Vin/Vout of this circuit:

[image]

I did like this:

The '+' input from the amplifier is \$V_{in} + 2.5V \$, and then the resistor divider \$ V_{out} = (V_{in} + 2.5V) \times 0.1 \$ and the capacitor dropping the tension would be \$ V_{out} = (V_{in} + 2.5V) \times 0.1 - Q/2\mu \$. Is this right?

Comment: What is the term, Q/2μ? Is that your capacitor? Is there a reason for including the cap in your analysis?

Comment: Where is the separate \$Q\$ term coming from? The charge on the capacitor is a consequence of Vin (including its variation in the time domain), and if you properly state your assumptions you may be able to treat the capacitor as a short for sufficiently high frequency AC inputs (it's in a common arrangement used to couple the AC component of the input while blocking DC)

Comment: No this is not correct. In order to affect \$V_{out}\$ an (AC) voltage would need to be dropped across the 2uF capacitor at the output. That capacitor has a certain **impedance** at a certain frequency. To drop a voltage across such an impedance, a **current** would need to flow. Can a current flow through the \$V_{out}\$ capacitor in this circuit? Hint: \$V_{out}\$ is unconnected....

Comment: Q/C or CV/C = V is not used correctly.  Xc=1/(2pi f C) is assumed to be 0 loss, but nice try ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input capacitor lets Vin (AC) through but doesn't pass any DC component from Vin. Then you have a voltage divider. It adds DC of 2.5V to Vin on the amplifier input. Well, technically, it's in a buffer configuration here, so LM324 output equals LM324 input voltage, because that's just how the buffer works.

So the output is 2.5V DC + Vin AC. Next comes the voltage divider, which takes 1/10th of everything, so the output of the voltage divider is (2.5V DC + Vin AC)*0.1 = 0.25V DC + 0.1Vin AC. Next comes the capacitor, which blocks DC, but lets AC through, so the output is 0.1Vin AC.

This circuit simply makes output equal to 1/10th of the input. Why did we need all this bias and extra components? Because AC goes both positive and negative, and you would have lost the negative part of the waveform if you have done things differently. (for example because the op amp can't output negative voltages without negative power rail - but we biased the whole thing up so that the signal that goes into output 1/10 divider is always positive, assuming DC bias is enough to make it always positive).

P.S. I'm talking in terms of perfect components and capacitors that block all DC and let all AC through, of course in real life capacitors have impedance for different frequencies and stuff, but this question seems to cover the basics with models made of perfect components